# Three lines that intersect in a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a condition for three lines ( = 1,2,3) in a plane given by $_  + _  = _$ to intersect in one point.

I decided to form a matrix and to find the identity matrix since it will tell me where all of the lines intersect. However, I stumble upon a problem because I don't know how to use the Gaussian elimination with the variables. Could I have some help, please?

Comment: Are the lines perhaps given by equations of the form '$ax+by=c$'? Or what are your box symbols representing?

Comment: The variables are unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

You have a system of $3$ equations with $2$ unknowns. The condition for such a system to have a solution is that these equations are linearly dependent, i.e. the determinant of the coefficients:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a_3&b_3&c_3
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
but the left-hand side of the equations have rank $2$, i.e. the submatrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\\a_3&b_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $2$.

Comment: Could all 3 lines be identical in this case?

Comment: @user84413: You're right, I didn't consider special cases, and my answer is incomplete. I'll update it in a moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  (I have edited your answer, but please change it if I made a mistake.)

Comment: That's fine. Actually the sole first condition is the condition for the $3$ lines to have a common point or be parallel. This is clearer if you work in the projective plane, for $3$ parallel lines are simply $3$ lines with a common point at $\infty$.